# how to use multiple time specific address in input scripts with difference balances?

Tags: script, transaction-input, binance

look at to the following transaction (withdraw transaction from binance)
https://blockchain.info/tx/404fd22d3d88d129975d03fe2993f0126db8f066b3d8126d6cca676747439515?show_adv=true

How in input scripts section same address reuse again and again with different balances?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the transaction inputs.

Simple example:

In your pocket, you have 100$ and 50$ and 10$ and if you want to pay for something that cost 160$ you will give the seller 100$, 50$ and 10$ in total 160$.

The same thing in here:

```
1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s (34.3721168 BTC - Output) 
1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s (10.03140713 BTC - Output) 
1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s (3.91377693 BTC - Output) 
1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s (14.88232237 BTC - Output) 
1NDyJtNTjmwk5xPNhjgAMu4HDHigtobu1s (8.29127328 BTC - Output)
```

in total 71 bitcoin

Comment: why  binance use same address multiple time !? it can be use binance can not use the address one time for inputs?

Comment: because they didn't get it from one sender, I sent 34 BTC, You sent 10 BTC to the same address. that is the result of more than one inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common practice that Exchanges uses permanent addresses to manage users funds and similar.
Sometimes it can happens however that even exchanges generate new different addresses each time you deposit or withdraw.